# Bitlocker and whole drive encryption?

Tags: bitlocker, disk-encryption

I understand that Bitlocker can encrypt a whole drive, but when I turn on Bitlocker, it really doesn't consume enough time to encrypt the whole drive.

Did it really do it in a couple of seconds or is there a gradual process to catch up?

Comment: See this FAQ....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-deployment-and-administration-faq

Comment: Sounds like you simply resumed BitLocker protection, from a suspended state, since enabling BitLocker on a device is not instantaneous and it is impossible it took only a couple of seconds.  **So the only explanation is your drive was already encrypted, the protection was suspended, and you simply resumed the protection.**

Comment: Is this Pro or Entreprise edition?   If so get into the Group Policy Editor and check the advanced bitlocker settings to toggle only new data, all, or re-encrpyt in place settings.